# Read from windows named pipe with cmd.exe or PowerShell or Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line, named-pipes

I'm looking for a quick way to check which data comes into a named pipe (on windows). Is there any way to do it from cmd.exe or powershell or python? Actually I found only ways to create named pipe and than manipulate it. But how can I open a named pipe created by another program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell allows you to use the entire .net api as such you can use the [pipe function in the framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The client can connect to a Windows named pipe as if it was any other file, provided it has been created by another program.  The low-level API is `CreateFile` using `ALWAYS_EXISTING`, but the ordinary language routines, like Python's `open` should work.  The filename will be \\ *server* \pipe\ *name*. 
Unlike disk files pipes are temporary, and when every handle to a pipe has been closed, the pipe and all the data it contains are deleted, so personally I maintain the pipe using a service where necessary.